# Having two x-servers although booting with second monitor turned off (and turned on later)

Tags: nvidia, monitor, xserver, multiple-monitors

I'm using a GT 730 chip with two monitors - LCD on DVI and TV on HDMI.
The LCD is the main monitor and it is used all the time for work and browsing. The TV is used occasionally, for movies, so it is usually turned off.

I configured the NVidia's settings, and now if the computer boots with both LCD and TV turned on, I get two X-Servers, each with its own desktop. So one person can work on the LCD while another person is watching a movie on the TV. That's great.

However, if I boot with the TV turned off, the 2nd X-Server doesn't open. So even when I turn on the TV I still don't get the 2nd X-Server. In fact I have to restart the x-server (sudo restart lightdm) but this closes all open programs on the LCD too.

Any idea how to solve that?
Is it possible to tell the OS to open the 2nd X-Server during boot even though the TV is off? or is it possible to open the 2nd X-Server automatically when the TV is turned on? or at least without restarting the lightdm service?

I'm on Xubuntu 14.04 and using xfce.

Thanks!
Assaf

Comment: Have you checked Settings > Displays ?